# How to get start and end dates from a time/date object created using a month or year in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, time

I have ISO 8601 compliant date strings like "2016" or "2016-09" representing year or months. How can I get start end dates from this.

for example:

```
2016    -> ["2016-01-01", "2016-12-31"]
2016-09 -> ["2016-09-01", "2016-09-30"]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
require 'date'

def iso8601_range(str)
  parts = str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  date = Date.new(*parts)
  case parts.size
  when 1
    date .. date.next_year - 1
  when 2
    date .. date.next_month - 1
  else
    date .. date
  end

end

iso8601_range('2016') # => 2016-01-01..2016-12-31
iso8601_range('2016-09') # => 2016-09-01..2016-09-30
iso8601_range('2016-09-20') # => 2016-09-20..2016-09-20
```

---

If you are cool with using `send` you can replace the `case` statement with

```
date .. date.send([:next_year,:next_month,:next_day][parts.size - 1]) - 1
```

Comment: edited, thx for comment (not sure if it were you  who left and deleted the comment). P.S. Too much work with Rails :)

Comment: Thanks @akuhn looks good. I was wondering if there are any built-in ways or gems to achieve the same. Seemed like a common time related problem.

Comment: Actually this will fail for boundary conditions in date:
iso8601_range("2016-08-31")

Comment: Good catch! Oh shoot, and it will also fail on `2016-12` then :(

Comment: Fixed, using `next_year` / `next_month` now.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

def create_start_end(string)
  year, month = string.split('-').map(&:to_i)
  if month && !month.zero?
    [Date.new(year, month, 1).to_s, Date.new(year, month, -1).to_s]
  else
    [Date.new(year, 1, 1).to_s, Date.new(year, 12, -1).to_s]
  end
end

create_start_end('2016')
#=> ["2016-01-01", "2016-12-31"]
create_start_end('2016-01')
#=> ["2016-01-01", "2016-01-31"]
create_start_end('2016-09')
#=> ["2016-09-01", "2016-09-30"]
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution in according to @AndreyDeineko :)

```
require 'date'

def create_date date
  date = date.split('-').map(&:to_i)
  [Date.new(*date, 1, 1), Date.new(*date, -1, -1)].map(&:to_s)
end
```

Comment: Hey! @AndreyDeineko, what you think about? :)